# Can we expect shots from Starman that include the Earth and Moon together?

Tags: spacex, the-moon, falcon-heavy, earth-observation, tesla-roadster

Just as the question asks.

Will the Roadster get anywhere near, or be in any planned position to capture images of the Earth and Moon in the same field of view?

A sort of "family photo" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that the moon is visible in the Roadster footage, so **a photo with the Earth and the moon is possible**. Here the moon can be seen in the lower left of the frame:

[image]

The Earth was visible in-frame about one minute before this frame. As the Roadster orbits the Earth the three objects should line up for a shot, especially with the wide-angle lens on the front camera. There are hours of footage, if I see a shot with both in-frame I'll update this answer with the definite **YES**.

**EDIT:**
This was a total [nerd snipe](https://xkcd.com/356/). The best "family photo" I could find was the *reflection* of the Earth on the bodywork with the moon in the background. **Enjoy!**

[image]

Comment: Ah, interesting! There's so much debris floating around the car all the time that I totally missed it down there! Thanks! Not exactly the image I was expecting, but damn it, space is just unimaginably big and everything else is just too damn small. If you find that shot, even though your's isn't the first answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the battery is already dead. Elon Musk estimated that it would die in 12 hours. The live feed stopped after four hours. Even if the battery is not dead, it would certainly be dead by the time the Roadster would be far enough to make this shot.

The 12 hour battery life expectancy comes from here in the press conference:

Comment: Thanks, Kim. I was going for the quick and dirty answer, but the reference helps.

Comment: Hmm, close one. I guess this means the shot I'm thinking of is ultimately a "no". Kind of a shame, but this was all way too cool anyway. Thanks for the info!