# Starman and Roadster: Position and camera

Tags: falcon-heavy, camera, tesla-roadster

We have a camera showing Starman, but no way to have the position ? At least distance from earth ?

How long till the camera stops or is out of range ?

Comment: Welcome on the Space SE! Your question looks unclear, please be more specific. Write more details, what you want, what tried, why it doesn't work.

Comment: I think I understand now that the live videos on youtube are old videos. That is why I wanted to know how is it that we still see the earth on this video, I wanted to know where it was, but it seems it's a fake live, those are old videos

Answer (score 1):

called2voyage provide part of this answer and kim holder edited to the response to provide a link to where Elon Mush answered this question about the battery life...

https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25019/23092

The short answer is battery life was expected to last 12 hours but only lasted 4 hours!

For the second part of your question in regard to positioning you will have to wait on someone with more knowledge in regard to this subject to answer your question.

I too have been greatly frustrated by my interest and desire to watch Starman sail off into the darkness of space with the view of the earth growing smaller all the time.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. So the "live" videos currently on youtube for Starman are old videos running in loop ?